# Unity c# control other scripts variables in realtime by registering variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In real time, i want to register a variable to my other scripts at start and want it to be controlled at realtime by other script.

public float leftTime;

MyManager.RegisterVariable(leftTime);

thats all, now i want my manager to control this variable by it self in update.
How can i make this?

Comment: See memory mapped io https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O

Comment: @Jay
Looks like it's not a good idea to use this with unity. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Maruas why not?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Jay
Looks like its not optimized in unity. You need to use some plugins etc to acces it.

Comment: Not so this has been optomized for a long time its just a stream, which oop over the bytes, pass the bytes duh early games worked like this forever

Comment: @Jay
No need to be mad. I am using unity & c# for long time. Not every c# fature work great in unity. I am coding a very optimized game here. As i saw on forums, people are not recommending to use this feature in unity.

Comment: Sorry I get offended easily when my solid work is ... questioned.

Comment: @MarufArtukoğlu Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Keep setter and getter functions in `MyManager` then take them and save them in `RegisterVariable`:

```
// in MyManager
static Action<float> varSetter;
static Func<float> varGetter;

static void RegisterVariable(Action<float> setter, Func<float> getter)
{
    varSetter = setter;
    varGetter = getter;
}

static void SomeFunction()
{
    float oldFloatValue = varGetter();
    float newFloatValue = oldFloatValue + 5f;
    varSetter(newFloatValue);
}
```

Then, when you call `RegisterVariable`, pass getter and setter. I recommend using anonymous functions if you don't plan on calling this frequently.

```
// in other script

float foobar = 5f;

void SomeOtherFunction()
{
    MyManager.RegisterVariable((f) => {foobar = f;}, ()=> {return foobar;});
}
```

Comment: remember to use static for your delegates or delegate*

Comment: consider multiple arguments you need to pass a span<byte>

Comment: this solution costs more to use than it did to implement!

Comment: Question asks about "a variable" (singular) more than multiple variables. Please clarify what you mean by "multiple arguments".

Comment: I wanna send 4 floats I gotta call the function 4 times?

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to return the ptr to the space or the Dictionary which contains the vars!

```
public interface IRunningStatistic
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Collects a value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    void Collect(decimal value);

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="IStatisticalFunction"/>'s which are run in the order inserted
    /// </summary>
    IList<IStatisticalFunction> Functions { get; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents a function
/// </summary>
public interface IStatisticalFunction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="IRunningStatistic"/> to which this instance belongs
    /// </summary>
    IRunningStatistic Statistic { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the function
    /// </summary>
    string Name { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A function accepting input
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    void Collect(decimal value);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all variables by name with their values
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Dictionary<string, decimal> GetState();

    //SetState / Load

    //Could use an array or dictionary 
}
```

```
class InternalFunctionRepresentation : IStatisticalFunction
        {
            public IRunningStatistic Statistic { get; private set; }

            public string Name { get; private set;}

            private readonly Action<decimal> Function;

            public InternalFunctionRepresentation(IRunningStatistic statistic, string name, Action<decimal> function)
            {
                (Statistic, Name, Function) = (statistic, name, function);
            }

            public void Collect(decimal value)
            {
                Function(value);
            }

            public Dictionary<string, decimal> GetState()
            {
    //if i was a byte[] this would be easyer 
                return new Dictionary<string, decimal>() { };
            }
        }
```